# Trouble with Timestamps when using `Lead` window function in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, sqldatatypes, window-functions

I'm attempting to get a customer's first order, their next order, and the difference in days between the two orders. Seems simple enough. The steps I followed were as follows:

1. Pull a customer's 1st and second order using the MIN() and LEAD() functions
2. Run DATEDIFF with those 2 fields to get the difference in days.

Brief code looks like this:

```
SELECT cust, MIN(ord_time) first_ord, LEAD(ord_time, 1) 
                                      OVER 
                                      (PARTITION BY customer_id
                                      ORDER BY ord_time) next_ord
FROM
(SELECT cust, ord_time
FROM df.orders
GROUP EACH BY cust, ord_time)
```

There are some other filtering joins and groupings in there, but that is the basic chunk.

The output should be a field with customer ids, and two timestamp fields. The two timestamp fields look like this:

[Timestamps in Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJqrd.png)

So everything looks great. But then, when I try to run the DATEDIFF() function with the two fields everything is coming back Null.

Additionally, when I hover over either timestamp field it tells me that the datatype is TIMESTAMP, but when I try to run any sort of timestamp conversion to seconds or anything else the next_ord field is causing it to fail with an error of "type unknown".

Just looking for anything I'm doing wrong or any way to work around this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is related to how wondow functions treat timestamps

This is what I see so far:

## 1.

When source datapoints are string - all works as **expected**:

```
SELECT 
  customer_id,
  first_ord,
  next_ord,
  DATEDIFF(next_ord, first_ord) AS diff
FROM (
  SELECT 
    customer_id, 
    LEAD(ord_time, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY ord_time) first_ord, 
    LEAD(ord_time, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY ord_time) next_ord,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY ord_time) num
  FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS customer_id, '2014-04-08 09:51:24 UTC' AS ord_time),
    (SELECT 1 AS customer_id, '2014-04-08 09:53:31 UTC' AS ord_time),
    (SELECT 1 AS customer_id, '2014-05-08 09:53:31 UTC' AS ord_time),
    (SELECT 2 AS customer_id, '2014-09-12 17:20:43 UTC' AS ord_time),
    (SELECT 2 AS customer_id, '2015-04-16 21:44:18 UTC' AS ord_time),
)
WHERE num = 1
```

with result:

```
customer_id       first_ord             next_ord    diff     
1   2014-04-08 09:51:24 UTC 2014-04-08 09:53:31 UTC 0    
2   2014-09-12 17:20:43 UTC 2015-04-16 21:44:18 UTC 216
```

## 2.

When source datapoints are timestamps - result is **null** as you stated in your question:

```
SELECT 
  customer_id,
  first_ord,
  next_ord,
  DATEDIFF(next_ord, first_ord) AS diff
FROM (
  SELECT 
    customer_id, 
    LEAD(ord_time, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY ord_time) first_ord, 
    LEAD(ord_time, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY ord_time) next_ord,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY ord_time) num
  FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS customer_id, TIMESTAMP('2014-04-08 09:51:24 UTC') AS ord_time),
    (SELECT 1 AS customer_id, TIMESTAMP('2014-04-08 09:53:31 UTC') AS ord_time),
    (SELECT 1 AS customer_id, TIMESTAMP('2014-05-08 09:53:31 UTC') AS ord_time),
    (SELECT 2 AS customer_id, TIMESTAMP('2014-09-12 17:20:43 UTC') AS ord_time),
    (SELECT 2 AS customer_id, TIMESTAMP('2015-04-16 21:44:18 UTC') AS ord_time),
)
WHERE num = 1
```

result:

```
customer_id       first_ord             next_ord    diff     
1   2014-04-08 09:51:24 UTC 2014-04-08 09:53:31 UTC null     
2   2014-09-12 17:20:43 UTC 2015-04-16 21:44:18 UTC null
```

## 3.

To "**fix**" this i had to do some casting as below:

```
SELECT 
  customer_id,
  TIMESTAMP(first_ord) as first_ord,
  TIMESTAMP(next_ord) as next_ord,
  DATEDIFF(next_ord, first_ord) AS diff
FROM (
  SELECT 
    customer_id, 
    LEAD(STRING(ord_time), 0) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY ord_time) first_ord, 
    LEAD(STRING(ord_time), 1) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY ord_time) next_ord,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY ord_time) num
  FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS customer_id, TIMESTAMP('2014-04-08 09:51:24 UTC') AS ord_time),
    (SELECT 1 AS customer_id, TIMESTAMP('2014-04-08 09:53:31 UTC') AS ord_time),
    (SELECT 1 AS customer_id, TIMESTAMP('2014-05-08 09:53:31 UTC') AS ord_time),
    (SELECT 2 AS customer_id, TIMESTAMP('2014-09-12 17:20:43 UTC') AS ord_time),
    (SELECT 2 AS customer_id, TIMESTAMP('2015-04-16 21:44:18 UTC') AS ord_time)
)
WHERE num = 1
```

result is:

```
customer_id       first_ord             next_ord    diff     
1   2014-04-08 09:51:24 UTC 2014-04-08 09:53:31 UTC 0    
2   2014-09-12 17:20:43 UTC 2015-04-16 21:44:18 UTC 216
```

Comment: This is great. I didn't think to do any casting inside the window function. All of my attempts were after already performing the calculation.